# Autocomplete vs. Geocoder APIs - Different Results

Tags: validation, geocoding, here-api

While working on address autocomplete demo and batch address validation feature for our multi country project, I've noticed there are differences in results for the same search text.

For instance, the address string `VIA KENNEDY 11, 24020 TORRE BOLDONE` (in Italy), on `Here` maps and `HERE` `geocoder autocomplete` (!) APIs, correctly resolves to `houseNumber` level.

When passed as single query or in batch `geocoder` validation, it's a `city` level match.

This significantly increases a number of "false negatives", and we have about 1M addresses (per country) to validate. Can anything be done to improve the matching?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The full name of that address is 'Via John Fitzgerald Kennedy'.

While the Autocomplete service is minded towards guessing the users intention and therefore tolerates omissions, the GeocoderAPI will not return a candidate whose match is not good enough.

So for example, the query 'via john kennedy 11, 24020 TORRE BOLDON' will return the expected address.